# How to update JTextArea in Java Swing?

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, jtextarea

I have a JComboBox named "jComboBox18" and a JTextArea "jTextArea11". Now I want that whenever a item is selected from the "jComboBox18" combo box its corresponding description is shown in the "jTextArea11" textarea.

I have added the appropriate listener to the JComboBox But the JTextArea is not showing any text. The code that I have written is as follows:

```
private void jComboBox18ItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {

    Object item = jComboBox18.getSelectedItem();

    if(item != null) {
        ems.logic.Process selectedProcess = (ems.logic.Process)item;

        jTextArea11.setText(selectedProcess.getProcessDescription());
        jTextArea11.updateUI();
        jTextArea11.revalidate();
        jTextArea11.validate();
    } 
}
```

=====================EDITED===========================================

The method is being called for sure. I am changing the state of one more combobox
which is also being written in this method and its state changes successfully whenever item is selected from the "jComboBox18"

Comment: Away from the question: I really hope in your real development-code the variables are named different.

Comment: To the problem directly: Can you verify, that this code is called if you select a new item?

Comment: So another function the method does is actually executed. So we have to investigate further. The code is guarded by an if-clause. Is the item != null, or asked differently: is the if-branch entered?

Comment: Yes, the if-branch entered and it also executes the line that sets the textarea but it is not reflecting any changes. This is strange for me too. I have worked with similar kinds of GUI various times but this thing never happened to me.

Comment: Strange. Another idea could be, that jTextArea11 does not point to the TextArea in question. Maybe it is the wrong variable or the variable gets later reassigned with a reference to a different TextArea. Away from that I'm out of debugging-options for the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think That should work. In fact, you should only need the setText() call. My guess is that you're function isn't getting called for some reason. Put a break point in your code and make sure it's getting called.

Answer (score 0):

In the code shown your method is named as `jComboBox18ItemStateChanged`. Are you sure this method is being called. The ItemListener for a JComboBox should implement the interface *ItemListener* which declares that the subclasses should implement the below method.

```
void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e);
```

How are you adding an instance of ItemListener to your JComboBox ?

EDIT:
After reading your edit and comments one another possiblity that I can think of is that:
you have a listener that is triggered when the textarea is updated and probably itis  undoing the changes done in JComboBox listener.